# What is the purpose of the CLS in the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, specifications, cls

I'm confused about the purpose of the [CLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (Common Language Specification) in the .NET Framework.

My understanding is that, with .NET, we can write a library with one language and use it in another language, and that the CLR enables this functionality. I do know that the purpose of the CLS is to fully interact with other objects regardless of the language they were implemented in.

What is the CLS exactly; what is its purpose?

Comment: The downvote probably came from someone who was unclear about what you were asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CLS is a guide-line intended for developers of components, as well as compiler-writers. It specifies what is allowed and what is not allowed in order to generate components, and build support for languages, in such a way that they are portable - and fully compatible to be consumed/interacted with from all CLS-compliant languages that can run in the CLR.

While the CLR has specifications that are exposed and enforced by the implementation. The CLS is just a guideline. You can still write components that break the CLS, but will work fine in the CLR. But in that case they might not be inter-operable with certain languages.

Obviously, the CLS is very important for compiler writers and language designers. But even as a component developer, it's important to stay within the lines of the CLS if you're striving for full inter-operability.

Answer (score 0):

> *I think with .Net we can write a library with one language and use it in another language and to do this there is the CLR, What is the CLS
>   exactly, what is its purpose?*

While this language integration is fantastic, the truth is that programming languages are very different, So to help you with this or to make `CLR` achieve this -

> Microsoft has defined the *Common Language Specification* (`CLS`) that
>   details for compiler vendors the minimum set of features their
>   compiler must support, if these compilers are to generate types
>   compatible with other components written by other CLS compliant
>   languages on top of the CLR.